# After change in Interface data contract WCF getting missing directives or assembly reference

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, interface, datacontract

My project was working fine but after adding the `DataContract` as shown below in interface `Iservice` I am getting errors,

```
[DataContract]    
public class Appending
{
     private string company;

     [DataMember]
     public string Company
     {
         get { return company; }
         set { company = value; }
     }
}
```

Here's the  error message :

**Error 199 'Services.Appending' does not contain a definition for 'Company' and no extension method 'Company' accepting a first argument of type 'Services.AppendixA' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

After the changes I rebuilt the Service succeessfully, updated service refrence in application, and restarted IIS.

I can access `company` in application by its object but error in running as i mentioned above.

Hopes for your suggestion 
thanks in advance

Comment: *I can access company in application by its object but error in running as i mentioned above* - do you mean you can see the Company type in your client-side, service-reference code?

Answer (score 0):

company is private, so WCF can't tranfer to client to use.

Try

```
[DataMember]
     public string Company
     {
         get;set;
     }
```